# Apache can't create more than 400 workers

Tags: apache, worker, limits

I have a webserver that should handle about 800 simultaneous connections. 
For this I have configured Apache 2.4 in worker mode (on Centos 6) with this values:

ServerLimit                 40
    StartServers                25
    MaxClients                  1000
    MinSpareThreads             25
    MaxSpareThreads             75
    MaxRequestWorkers           1000
    ThreadsPerChild             25
    MaxConnectionsPerChild      0

However, when I check the server-status I can not see more than 400 workers simultaneously.
In error_log file I can see this: "[mpm_worker:error] [pid 2559:tid 140190319810368] AH00286: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting", but increasing this value has no effect. (with stop/start apache after each change in configuration file).
I checked the ulimits and for apache user the value of nproc is 2048.
I mention that Apache was compiled by me and I didn't set explicitly any limit at compilation time.

What could be the cause of this limitation?

Comment: If you set MaxRequestWorkers in apache2.conf, remind it is overwritten by /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured out what was causing the issue. In httpd.conf the settings for worker module were declared before loading the module, so they were ignored by apache. Moving them after "LoadModule" section fixed the problem.

Comment: That's the same than setting in module configuration as suggested before.